# Where to put common code found in multiple models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mixins

I have two models that contain the same method:

```
def foo
  # do something
end
```

Where should I put this?

I know common code goes in the **`lib` directory** in a Rails app.

But if I put it in a new class in `lib` called '`Foo`', and I need to add its functionality to both of my `ActiveRecord models`, do I do that like this:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
includes Foo

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
includes Foo
```

and then both `A` and `B` will contain the `foo` method just as if I had defined it in each?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Create a module, which you can put in the `lib` directory:

```
module Foo
  def foo
    # do something
  end
end
```

You can then `include` the module in each of your model classes:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Foo
end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Foo
end
```

The `A` and `B` models will now have a `foo` method defined.

If you follow Rails naming conventions with the name of the module and the name of the file (e.g. Foo in foo.rb and FooBar in foo_bar.rb), then Rails will automatically load the file for you. Otherwise, you will need to use `require_dependency 'file_name'` to load your lib file.

Answer (score 14):

You really have two choices:

1. Use a module for common logic and include it in A & B
2. Use a common class C that extends ActiveRecord and have A & B extend C.

Use #1 if the shared functionality is not core to each class, but applicable to each class. For example:

```
(app/lib/serializable.rb)
module Serializable
  def serialize
    # do something to serialize this object
  end
end
```

Use #2 if the shared functionality is common to each class and A & B share a natural relationship:

```
(app/models/letter.rb)
class Letter < ActiveRecord::Base
  def cyrilic_equivilent
    # return somethign similar
  end
end

class A < Letter
end

class B < Letter
end
```

Comment: in this case, there is a need of a 'letters' relation, right? What about doing the same and actually extending activerecord to A and B?

Comment: Option #2 makes Rails assume that A and B are both stored in a table called "letters".  If you only want shared logic, while keeping A and B in separate tables, an abstract parent class is the way to go, as @Ron pointed out [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20749863/2657571).

Answer (score 6):

Here's how I did it...  First create the mixin:

```
module Slugged
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_many :slugs, :as => :target
    has_one :slug, :as => :target, :order => :created_at
  end
end
```

Then mix it into every model that needs it:

```
class Sector < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Slugged

  validates_uniqueness_of :name
  etc
end
```

It's almost pretty!

To complete the example, though it's irrelevant to the question, here's my slug model:

```
class Slug < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :target, :polymorphic => true
end
```

Answer (score 5):

One option is to put them in a new directory, for example `app/models/modules/`. Then, you can add this to `config/environment.rb`:

```
Dir["#{RAILS_ROOT}/app/models/modules/*.rb"].each do |filename|
  require filename
end
```

This will `require` every file in in that directory, so if you put a file like the following in your modules directory:

```
module SharedMethods
  def foo
    #...
  end
end
```

Then you can just use it in your models because it will be automatically loaded:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include SharedMethods
end
```

This approach is more organized than putting these mixins in the `lib` directory because they stay near the classes that use them.

Comment: If both models call "before_save :before_method" and I also put this in SharedMethods, will that work too? Or does it only work for the method definitions?

Comment: Also, does it matter where your 'require' code appears in environment.rb?

Comment: You'll probably want it in the "Rails::Initializer.run do |config| ... end" section

Comment: And, yes, the method "before_method" can be in a mixin, but the code "before_save :before_method" cannot.

Comment: It is possible to add the before_save call to the mixin. I've added an answer that shows how.

Answer (score 5):

If you need **ActiveRecord::Base** code as a part of your common functionalities, using an abstract class could be useful too. Something like:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  #Here ActiveRecord specific code, for example establish_connection to a different DB.
end

class A < Foo; end
class B < Foo; end
```

As simple as that. Also, if the code is not ActiveRecord related, please find `ActiveSupport::Concerns` as a better approach.

Answer (score 4):

As others have mentioned include Foo is the way to do things... However it doesn't seem to get you the functionality you want with a basic module. The following is the form a lot of Rails plugins take to add class methods and new callbacks in addition to new instance methods.

```
module Foo #:nodoc:

  def self.included(base) # :nodoc:
    base.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    include Foo::InstanceMethods

    before_create :before_method
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    def foo
      ...
    end

    def before_method
      ...
    end
  end 

end
```

Comment: I tried that method, but it still tells me that there is no method defined (in my case, `scope`).