# Where to put custom callbacks that I use in several models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, callback

Let's say I have two models that both have same callbacks:

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :patient
    validates :text, presence: true
    after_validation :normalizeDate

    def normalizeDate
      self.created_at = return_DateTime(self.created_at)
    end
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    after_validation :normalizeDate

    def normalizeDate
      self.created_at = return_DateTime(self.created_at)
    end
end
```

Where can I put the shared callback code? Thanks

```
 def normalizeDate
   self.created_at = return_DateTime(self.created_at)
 end
```

Comment: It's not validation code. It's callback.

Comment: Sorry! I will change my question

Comment: I think this is a good question but just a side-note: If you only have 2 models, duplication is fine.

Comment: @sytycs Dry is Dry my friend :) 2 times the same code is already duplication, just imagine your self having to maintain your code few months later, and forgot to update one of the 2?

Comment: @BenjaminSinclaire I disagree. If in 2 months time I decide to change the way my Dates are normalised I will probably think about the 2 places in my code where that happens. I just don't like to jump the gun on refactoring. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298272/how-much-duplicated-code-do-you-tolerate

Comment: It's your right to disagree :) In my experience it never work like that. You will come back on your code most of the time, and most of the time your mind will be focus somewhere else.

Comment: @BenjaminSinclaire haha could be :) thanks for being a good sport.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Marek's answer is good but the Rails way is:

```
module NormalizeDateModule
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    after_validation :normalize_date
  end

  def normalize_date
    self.created_at = return_DateTime(created_at)
  end
end
```

[Doc here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html).

(and you have a decicated folder for it: models/concerns)

Comment: Right. I forgot about `Concern`.

Comment: And how do i call it in my model?

Comment: @JohnSmith The same way as in my solution.

Comment: To test your solution i put `self.created_at = self.created_at + 2.days` into `def normalize_date`. But i always get the error: `undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass` because `self.created` seems not to be defined! What do i wrong? Thanks

Comment: @JohnSmith `created_at` is `nil` until the object is created. replace with: `self.created_at = (created_at || Time.now) + 2.days`

Answer (score 3):

You can define your own module:

```
module NormalizeDateModule
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      after_validation :normalize_date
    end
  end

  def normalize_date
    self.created_at = return_DateTime(created_at)
  end
end
```

and include it in every class you want this behavior:

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  include NormalizeDateModule
  # ...
end
```

I'm not sure if my code is free of error (I didn't test it), treat it as an example.

Comment: The above code will work if you make it a Module instead of `class NormalizeDateModule` and include. Refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698225/where-to-put-common-code-found-in-multiple-models which also uses the above code. The user had marked it as valid answer.

Comment: @SreekanthGS of course. I meant `module` yet I wrote `class`. :) Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for this question, but where do i have to save the modul? I mean in the `models`-folder as `normalize_date_module.rb`?

Comment: @JohnSmith yes, I think `models` folder is most appropriate for this. And yes, it should be named as you wrote.

Comment: @JohnSmith no, since it is meant to be reused over many models, it should be placed in separate file.

Comment: To test your solution i put `self.created_at = self.created_at + 2.days` into `def normalize_date`. But i always get the error: `undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass` because `self.created` seems not to be defined! What do i wrong? Thanks

Comment: @JohnSmith `created_at` is `nil` before saving record.

Comment: I dont think so because it is set with the parameters, and with my old validtion i worked!

Comment: @JohnSmith but your error message clearly states that `created_at` is `nil`. I'm quite sure this error doesn't come from this callback calling way.

Answer (score 2):

The Rails 4 way is to use `ActiveSupport::Concern`

File **models/concerns/date_normalizer.rb**

```
module Concerns
  module DateNormalizer
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do |base|
      base.after_validation :normalize_date
    end

    def normalize_date
      self.created_at = return_DateTime(self.created_at)
    end
  end
end
```

File **model/entry.rb**

```
class Entry < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Concerns::DateNormalizer

  belongs_to :patient
  validates :text, presence: true
end
```

File **models/post.rb**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Concerns::DateNormalizer
end
```

Note: I renamed for you `normalizeDate` to `normalize_date`

Comment: So far nicest answer! Ill check it out!

Comment: There is already a folder `concerns` in `models` should i put the `date_normalizer.rb` there? Thanks

Comment: Sorry it's an habit of mine to have several concerns directories, better to use the rails default for a start

Comment: Sorry but i get a error for your code: `wrong argument type Class (expected Module)` for: `include Concerns::DateNormalizer`. Do you know how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: Yes off course, it's `module DateNormalizer` instead of `class DateNormalizer`. My bad. I edited my comment

Comment: To test your solution i put `self.created_at = self.created_at + 2.days` into `def normalize_date`. But i always get the error: `undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass` because `self.created` seems not to be defined! What do i wrong? Thanks

Comment: That's another problem: I assume you are testing on a new record, and for new records, at the time of validation (because your callback is `after_validation`) the field `created_at` is not yet set by rails

Comment: The fact that you have this error means that your callback is correctly working (because the error is from your code in the call back)

Comment: Thanks! What could i do so that it also works for new records?

Comment: Kindly validate this answer and post another question, or it will become confusing

Comment: Because its not related to your original question, let's keep stack overflow clean :)