# Rails: No method error after renaming a class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just renamed a class and now my app breaks with a

```
NoMethodError in MailchimpController#campaigns 
undefined method `new' for MailchimpHelper:Module`
```

when trying to instantiate this class. The class was named `mailchimp_wrapper.rb` and now goes by the name `mailchimp_helper.rb`. A shortened version looks like this, where I obviously changed the name accordingly from `MailchimpWrapper` to `MailchimpHelper`:

```
class MailchimpHelper

  def initialize
    @api_key = "jgkgkgkljg"
    @mc_user = "lkjlkjlkjlj"     
    @api_endpoint = 'https://us5.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/'
  end

  def get_campaigns
    campaigns
  end
end
```

`MailchimpController` looks like this:

```
class MailchimpController < ApplicationController

  def campaigns
    mailchimp = MailchimpHelper.new
    campaigns_hash = mailchimp.get_campaigns
    @campaigns = campaigns_hash["campaigns"]
  end
end
```

Is there something else I have to do when renaming classes?
It somehow doesn't seem to treat `MailchimpHelper` as a class but as a module as the error message suggests. But I have no idea where to go from here..

Comment: Try changing `MailchimpHelper` to something which doesn't end with `Helper`. Rails might be treating it differently. Check if there already exist a `mailchimp_helper.rb` in helpers as you already got `MailchimpController`

Comment: True, there is a file named `mailchimp_helper.rb`. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `helper MailchimpHelper` to the `MailchimpController` class.

```
class MailchimpController < ApplicationController
  helper MailchimpHelper

  def campaigns
    mailchimp = MailchimpHelper.new
    campaigns_hash = mailchimp.get_campaigns
    @campaigns = campaigns_hash["campaigns"]
  end
end
```

EDIT

Alternatively you can try changing the `MailchimpHelper` class to a `module`.

Name it `mailchimp.rb`.

```
module Mailchimp
  # no need to an initialize with modules
  @api_key = "jgkgkgkljg"
  @mc_user = "lkjlkjlkjlj"     
  @api_endpoint = 'https://us5.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/'

  def get_campaigns
    campaigns
  end
end
```

Then, in your `MailchimpController` you need to add `include Mailchimp`. And when you want to call the module methods you do not need to instantiate a new class. So your example controller would look like this:

```
class MailchimpController < ApplicationController
  include Mailchimp

  def campaigns
    campaigns_hash = get_campaigns
    @campaigns = campaigns_hash["campaigns"]
  end
end
```

Comment: Maybe I should have mentioned that `mailchimp_helper`is located in `app/models`. Or is that not relevant?

Comment: So `mailchimp_helper` is not a helper? Or not supposed to be a helper?

Comment: It provides functionality for Mailchimp but I never made use of `app/helpers`so probably it is not a helper in the strict sense. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Hmm well typically the best way to include code/functionality from another file is to [use a module](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1698225/1241782). That question specifically asks about models but you can do the same thing for controllers. Is there a reason you want it to be a class instead of a module?

Comment: Nope, as long as I can do what I wanna do I don't mind if it is a class or a module. As the code was in a class before I changed the name I just kept it like that. Changing the names to `mailchimp.rb` respectively `Mailchimp`didn't help and weirdly I get the same error.

Comment: I would recommend trying it as a module then. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot. Where would you save/place this module?

Comment: Keeping it in your `/app/models` directory should be fine. Some people like to put modules in `/lib` though; however, that might require you to add `/lib` to the autoload path for your Rails app.

Comment: I kept it in /app/models and still it won't work, giving me a method not found error for the module which doesn't make sense. I've got the feeling I am missing something in the bigger picture, maybe related to versioning or so.. anyways, thanks again for you time and help, Mike.

Comment: Can you copy and paste the exact error message you're getting now?

Comment: That's `NoMethodError in MailchimpController#campaigns
undefined method 'get_campaigns' for Mailchimp:Module`. I added a 'Mailchimp' before calling the method of the Module so that I have `    campaigns_hash = Mailchimp.get_campaigns`.

Comment: Did you try both **with** and **without** adding `Mailchimp` before the `get_campaigns` call? It should not be there. When you include a module in a class it directly adds instance methods to that class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106038/discussion-between-flip-and-mike).